# Error message while executing a function for extracting time-series values using spatial points

Tags: r, list, raster

I have a function to extract values of timeseries raster for path of points. That was working perfectly up to now; however, I am constantly receiving error trying to use it today. The error I am receiving says:

> Error in UseMethod("extract_") : no applicable method for
>   'extract_' applied to an object of class "c('RasterLayer', 'Raster',
>   'BasicRaster')"

Can you please help. I have tried a lot but I am not able to resolve this issue.

```
library(raster)
#--------------------------------------start myfunction-----------------------------

# extract raster values for each single point in each path and put it a dataframe
lst <- function (rstack.lst, points, df.name, IDstr){
  df.name <- list()
  ii <- 1
  #number of layers in a list of raster stacks
  n = Reduce(`+`, lapply(rstack.lst, nlayers))

  for (j in 1:length(rstack.lst)){
    df.name[[j]] <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = nlayers(rstack.lst[[j]])+3, nrow = nrow(points)))
    names(df.name[[j]]) <- append(c("coords.x","coords.y","ID"), substr(names(rstack.lst[[j]]),5,14), after = 3)
    #calculating x and y coordinates
    df.name[[j]][1:2] <- coordinates(points) 
    # setting up unique IDs 
    df.name[[j]]$ID <- paste0(IDstr, ".",seq(1:(nrow(df.name[[j]])))) 

    for (i in 1:nlayers(rstack.lst[[j]])){
      df.name[[j]][i+3] <- extract(rstack.lst[[j]][[i]], points)
      colnames(df.name[[j]][i+3]) <- substr(names(rstack.lst[[j]][[i]]),5,14)
      cat(paste0(round((ii/(n))*100), '% completed'))
      ii <- ii+1
      Sys.sleep(.05)
      if (ii == n) cat(': Done')
      else cat('\014')
    }

  }
  return(df.name)
}
#--------------------------------------end start myfunction-----------------------------

lsdata[[1]] <- lst(rstack.lst=r.lst, points=Pnt.shp, IDstr="P1")
```

Comment: Looks like your function uses the wrong `extract` function. Try reloading the package or add `raster::` to extract. Also, just an unsolicited and well meant tip: If you have nested loops in R, chances are big your function could be much fore efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be wrong but I think the `extract` function is not malfunctioning but you are probably loading some other packages with exactly the same function (I meant with the same name). There are many packages that may have a function with a **same name**. For instance, `extract` is also a function in `tidyr`. To avoid these kinds of issues, I suggest you to also add the package name while specifying the function. Here you can do: `raster::extract`.

To make sure, simply execute `extract` and doublecheck what it contains. Whatever it contains, probably it is not be as below:

```
function (x, y, ...) 
standardGeneric("extract")
<bytecode: 0x000000001873c4d0>
<environment: 0x000000001855db68>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x, y
Use  showMethods("extract")  for currently available ones.
```

Comment: you are totally right, thanks for saving me!